# Merging data frames by date in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge

I have a 8 dataframes which contain date and a stock return. They are of different length (some 5 years, some 8, etc.). Some of them are randomly non-defined (depends on what the user do before - which countries she chooses). What I want to do, is to merge by date only those dataframes which have data and to find correlation between the columns. Please, advise me this issue. I use 
the command below to merge data frames, but because some of them do not exist (this is random) I can not merge them.

```
    merged =pd.concat([germany_return, france_return, usa_return, hongkong_return, india_return, japan_return, england_return, china_return], axis=1)
```

Below I present the last part of the code:

```
#Define Stock Price colum
stock_germany = data_germany['Settle'] 
stock_france = data_france['Settle'] 
stock_usa = data_usa['Value'] 
stock_hongkong = data_hongkong['Last Traded']
stock_india = data_india['Close']
stock_japan = data_india['Close']
stock_england = data_england['Settle']
stock_china = data_china['Value']

#Calculate Monthly returns
germany_return = stock_germany.pct_change(21)
france_return = stock_france.pct_change(21)
usa_return = stock_usa.pct_change(21)
hongkong_return = stock_hongkong.pct_change(21)
india_return = stock_india.pct_change(21)
japan_return = stock_japan.pct_change(21)
england_return = stock_england.pct_change(21)
china_return = stock_china.pct_change(21)

merged =pd.concat([germany_return, france_return, usa_return, hongkong_return, india_return, japan_return, england_return, china_return], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right.. should be stock_japan = data_japan['Close']

Comment: Is it giving you any specific error?  Because if you are just wanting to add the dataframes along the column axis together the `pd.concat()` function should work.